# C++ minor problem: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void"

Tags: c++, constructor, mergesort

I'm new to C++ and run into the following problem when trying to implement a simple recursive algorithm. The problem is highlighting the `sorted_lst.push_back(last[0])` in the base case return and says: `no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void" to "std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int>>"C/C++(415)` . Now, I don't see where my void is since I have a return of a `vector` and not `void`. I don't even know what a constructor is in this case, since I have a function and not a class?

```
vector<int> merge_sorting(vector<int> lst, vector<int> sorted_lst = vector<int>()) {

    if (lst.size() == 1){
        return sorted_lst.push_back(lst[0]);
    };
    vector <int> llst(lst.begin(), lst.begin() + (lst.size()/2));
    vector <int> rlst(lst.begin() + (lst.size()/2), lst.end());
    vector<int> a = merge_sorting(llst, sorted_lst);
    vector<int> b = merge_sorting(rlst, sorted_lst);
    // ...
```

Comment: It's push_back that returns void not your function. Presumably you mean to push_back to sorted_lst and then return it, i.e. `{ sorted_lst.push_back(lst[0]); return sorted_lst; }`

Comment: Alternately you could just return `lst` without doing anything at all to `sorted_lst` in that situation. ETA: I'm wrong, that only works when `sorted_lst` is empty, but the function behavior for when `lst.size() == 1` and `sorted_lst` is non-empty doesn't look like an accurate implementation of merge sort to me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Tumblweed53` pointed out, you are returning the void which was returned by `push_back`. You can do the following instead:

```
vector<int> merge_sorting(vector<int> lst, vector<int> sorted_lst = vector<int>()) {

    if (lst.size() == 1){
        sorted_lst.push_back(lst[0]);
        return sorted_lst;
    };
    vector <int> llst(lst.begin(), lst.begin() + (lst.size()/2));
    vector <int> rlst(lst.begin() + (lst.size()/2), lst.end());
    vector<int> a = merge_sorting(llst, sorted_lst);
    vector<int> b = merge_sorting(rlst, sorted_lst);
```

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector<T>::push_back` returns `void`

You probably meant to return `sorted_lst` itself.

Refer to docs on `push_back` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back